# Splitting string into words with regex

Tags: python, regex

How can I split string with regex into words not longer than 3 characters like:

**Input**

```
"ads1323z123123c123123890sdfakslk123klaad,313ks"
```

**Output**

```
['ads', 'z', 'c', 'ks']
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can also use lookahead and lookbehind expressions to match only 3-character words:

```
import re
s = "ads1323z123123c123123890sdfakslk123klaad,313ks"
re.findall('(?<![a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z]{1,3}(?![a-zA-Z])', s)
```

Output:

```
['ads', 'z', 'c', 'ks']
```

The regular expression works like this: the middle part `[a-zA-Z]{1,3}` says "match 1 to 3 alphabetic characters". The first part `(?<![a-z][A-Z])` is a negative lookbehind assertion that asserts that the 3 alphabetic characters are not preceded by an alphabetic character.  the last part `(?![a-zA-Z])` is a negative lookahead assertion that asserts that the 3 alphabetic characters are not followed by an alphabetic character.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.split`:

```
import re
s = "ads1323z123123c123123890sdfakslk123klaad,313ks"
results = list(filter(lambda x:len(x) <= 3, re.split('[^a-zA-Z]+', s)))
```

Output:

```
['ads', 'z', 'c', 'ks']
```